# what will happen for this line "a=0.0,a := nz(a[1], high)"

Tags: pine-script

I am new to the pine script, can anyone help me to understand what happing in the following code

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
a=0.0,a := nz(a[1], high)
plot(a)
```

I just backtesting the open-source code, but stuck with that line, like what happing there, it's pleasure, if anyone explains the logic.

In Chart it's plots a plain line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU2oN.png)

Answer (score 3):

First you declared float variable `a` with initial value of `0.0`

```
a=0.0
```

Then you referencing to the history of that variable by `a[1]`. In the first bar (`bar_index` 0) of the dateset there is no previous value of `a`, so `a[1]` returns `na` (not avaliable or NaN).

```
a := nz(a[1], high)
```

After that you using that value in the `nz()` function, which is

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_nz

`nz(x, y)` - returns x if it's a valid (not NaN) number, otherwise y

So, as `a[1]` at the first bar is `na`, then `nz(a[1], high)` returns `high`, which is the `high` value of that bar.

And then this `high` value is assigned to the `a`:

```
a := nz(a[1], high)
```

At the next bar (`bar_index` = 1) `nz(a[1], high)` returns previous history value of `a` (`high` of `bar_index` 0), because now `a[1]` is not `na`.

After that you plot the same value in the next bars.

Comment: Thank you. it helped me to correct the error that i was getting in script V5